# International JRE6 or JDK6 or reading a file in "cp037" encoding scheme

Tags: java, programming-languages, character-encoding, db2

I have been trying to read a file in "cp037" encoding scheme using JAVA. I able to read a file in basic encoding schemes like UTF-8, UTF16 etc...After a bit of research on the internet i came to know that we need charset.jar or international version of JRE be installed to support extended encoding schemes. Can anyone send me a link for international version of JRE6 or JDK6. or is there any better way that i could read a file in cp037 encoding scheme.

P.S: cp037 is a character encoding scheme supported by IBM Mainframes. All i need is to display a file in windows, which is being generated on IBM Mainframes machine, using a java program.

Thanks in advance for your help... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this webpage](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html) for Java 5 (note, it might be different for Java 6). There is no special, separate "international" version of the JRE or JDK; however, the `lib\charsets.jar` may or may not be installed on your system depending on what your operating system supports.

Are you sure there is no `charsets.jar` in your JRE installation directory? On my system, it's under `%JDK_HOME%\jre\lib`. (Note: NOT under `%JDK_HOME%\lib`).

Search your system to see if you already have `charsets.jar` somewhere. (Note that it's called `charsets.jar` with an s, not `charset.jar`).

Comment: you are right! it's charsets.jar. I dont have it in standard distribution. I could find i18n.jar, which supports extended character set. I have put that i18n.jar file in jre\lib  but not working tough!

Answer (score 1):

> After a bit of research on the internet i came to know that we need charset.jar or international version of JRE be installed to support extended encoding schemes.

Are you sure that this charset isn't included in the standard distribution though?

This code works fine for me on jdk 1.6.0_17 64bit (Windows):

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("cp037");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(f), charset));

String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("read line: " + line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different code with Java 1.6 on WinXP getting text from Mainframe over the web upload:

```
String text = new String(data, 0, data.length, "Cp037");
text = text.replace('', 'a');
text = text.replace('Ý', '[');
text = text.replace('¨', ']');
```

Note, that there are several characters, which need special attention.

Answer (score 1):

As Reddy says sometimes the charsets.jar is there, however, the issue still exists.

The only solution I found was to add the jar to the jre system libraries using the buildpath funcionality of eclipse.

The change was done to the default windows java version.

A different option would be to instal jdk instead of jre.

Some info links about the java encode schemes:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/readme-142177.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Comment: I found a new solution for this issue and you can download a standard JRE version from the oracle site and do not run the file, just open a command line window and run it in the following way: C:\<Downloaded JRE file location> ADDLOCAL=ALL  /passive. That should install the JRE international version, good luck!